# read number from .txt file and replace string in .tex file

Tags: sed, grep, cygwin, latex, miktex

I have a text file with following content
aaaa = 1000

I want to replace bbbb in LaTeX file with 1000 that I got from text file

I have tried following codes but did not work.

set motor_loc = `grep -i 'aaaa' motor.txt | awk '{print $2}'`

`sed -i 's/bbbb/$motor_loc/' for_pdf.tex> for_pdf.tex.tmp`

At this point, bbbb is changed to $motor_loc

Then, when I tried to create pdf with following line, it gives me an error.

`pdflatex for_pdf.tex`

How can I change bbbb to 1000 (value read from text file) instead of $motor_loc or string.

FYI, I am using Cygwin and Miktex and will try to run this code in Raspberry Pi 2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes in the arguments to `sed` keep your variable from being expanded, so go from single quotes to double quotes

```
user@thoth:~$ FOO=ABC
user@thoth:~$ echo $FOO
ABC
user@thoth:~$ echo "$FOO"
ABC
user@thoth:~$ echo '$FOO'
$FOO
```

Another sort of quotes that can also be useful are back ticks, that change the output of a command into strings.

```
user@thoth:~$ FOO=`ls *.txt`
user@thoth:~$ echo $FOO
soap.txt
```

EDIT:  a different form of command substitution seems to be more commonly used in bash scripts these days

```
 FOO=$(ls *.txt)
```

There are apparent differences on how backslashes are handled in the command for instance

Comment: Thank you! Actually it worked except that I found another problem... When I manually type `motor_loc=1000` Then it works, but I realize that following line does not read value from motor.txt `set motor_loc = grep -i 'aaaa' motor.txt | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: I don't know if you tried to put backticks in there or not.  markup in comments is awkward.  since code is marked up by enclosure in backticks in a comment, how does one put backticks inside code in comments on stackoverflow

Comment: I added backticks into the answer

Comment: I think I can solve this problem with back ticks. Thank you again for your help. :)

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if backticks are too old school.  All the cool kids seem to be using the form `FOO=$(ls *.txt)` , and perhaps there is some subtle distinction or arvantage I've missed.   I probably think of using backticks first because of similar usage in perl.